# Configure Windows Server 2016 Firewall for FTP

Tags: windows, iis, firewall, ftp, windows-server-2016

What ports need to be open for IIS FTP servers on a Firewall and how to best do it and is it possible to configure the  Firewall for IIS FTP that I have opened the right ports and it is good ?

Just opened port 21 but the server is not available, when opening all the ports the server is running.

> p.s. As I understand from the wiki you need to open 21/TCP for commands, 20/TCP for data and 49152-65534/TCP dynamically.

#### update:

[image]

[Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776089/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-windows-2016-firewall-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-ftp) version

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you wrote that you opened just port 21. Then you write that you understand that you need to open more ports. What did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

I just created a 'New Rule' - opening TCP 20-21 and got it working.
Microsoft default FTP Rules were still in place and activated, but were blocking the connection.

Comment: I had to do the same. The only difference is the allowed program (anything instead of `svchost.exe`, which I cannot change)

Answer (score 1):

When you install IIS, it preconfigures firewall rules in Windows Firewall.

You may just need to enable those rules to make it working.

Go to *Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules* and locate three *"FTP server"* rules. Make sure they are enabled. For details, see my article on [Installing a secure FTP Server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#window_firewall).

---

If this does not help, you need to give us more details. Particularly, what exact problem/error message are you getting. *"Is not available"* is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **reset** Windows 2016 server for preconfigures firewall rules in Windows Firewall start working.
I had exactly same problem on few Windows server.

Comment: This explains nothing.  Please be more explicit.